# sliding menu with plus/minus toggle functionality

Tags: jquery

I have sliding toggle menu which when clicked opens up the hidden div. There are 4 headings in h4 tag which has its own description in a div and the divs are hidden. So, when a user clicks a heading the hidden div slides down and the content shows up. Now I need a plus/minus toggle so that a user can understand something is there under the heading.Here is my code

```
 <div class="getInsSection">
    <!--Start sec1-->
    <div class="sec1">
        <h4>HEADING 1 <span>-</span></h4>
      <div class="hideit first">
        <p>
            Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--End sec1-->

    <!--Start sec2-->
    <div class="sec2">
        <h4>HEADING 2</h4>
      <div class="hideit">
        <p>
            Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--End sec2-->

    <!--Start sec3-->
    <div class="sec3">
        <h4>HEADING 3</h4>
      <div class="hideit">
        <p>
            Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--End sec3-->

    <!--Start sec4-->
    <div class="sec4">
        <h4>HEADING 4</h4>
      <div class="hideit">
        <p>
            Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--End sec4-->

  </div>
```

Jquery code

```
 $(window).load(function () {
    $('.first').show();
 });
 $(document).ready(function (){
    $('.hideit').hide();
    $('div:has(".hideit")').find('h4').click(function() {
       var elem = $(this).next('.hideit');
       if (elem.is(':visible')) {
           elem.slideUp();
       } else {
           ($('.hideit').slideUp()) (elem.slideDown());
       }
    });
 });
```

Here is [link](http://jsbin.com/oyufid/3/edit) for demo.

Comment: You'd be better off with jQueryUI Accordion http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: Check this link http://designgala.com/how-to-expand-collapse-toggle-div-layer-using-jquery/ it will be helpful

Comment: I think I have found what I was looking for its Vallenato and now I will have to play a little bit.